# JS function not loading from another file

Tags: javascript, ajax, function

I'm trying to load a notify function in javascript from another file.

I have a function called showSuccess() that works when I call it in my AJAX code function but when I try to call another one I just created, it is not working.

I have tried clearing my cookies and sessions so it must be the code.

When I put the function above my AJAX function, it works. But not when I try to call the function from another page. Like I said it works when I try to call showSuccess which is pretty weird as it's exactly the same function code as the one below, I just changed the `text:` .

My js function I'm trying to load from another file :

```
//My console success notify
function update_myConsole_success() {
    $.gritter.add({
        class_name: "-success",
        title: "Success!",
        text: "You have successfully updated your consoles credentials.",
        time: 6e3
    })
};
```

My ajax function :

```
<script>
function updateMyAccount() {
  var notify = document.getElementById("myConsoleNotify").value;
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "includes/form_submit.php",
      data: {
        SaveConsoleChanges: true,
        consoleNotify: notify
      },
      success: function(msg){
        if(msg == 1) {
          update_myConsole_success();
        } else {
          general_error_forms();
        }
      },
  });
return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that might be because file contains "update_myConsole_success" function might be loading last from the calling function file , see the network of the console.

Make sure file containing update_myConsole_success function will load first

Comment: yes that might be because you file is not loading first. check network from the console

Comment: Oh I figured why. My text editor wasn't updating my text so I re-opened my project and pasted the code and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Include external js script tag before your page script.
2. Put your code in $(document).ready() event.